# Custom Javascript not loded properly in magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Custom Javascript is not working with infinite scroll or after applying some filters from shopping options

[image]

Working Fine with the first 12 products. but after applying some filters or working with the products after 12 it is not functioning.

Here is my JS code

```
require(['jquery'],
function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.compare_check').click(function() {
            alert('hello');
        });

    });
});
```

I am working with the custom Add to compare functionality !!

Comment: I think Because after 12 products load dynamic your JS is not getting bind, you have to bind JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code,

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('click','.compare_check',function(){
         alert('hello')
    });
});
```

If still it is not working then check after applied the filter some other js is working so add this code with that function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .click only works for elements already on the page. You have to use something like on if you are wiring up future element.

```
require(['jquery'],
function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("html").on("click",".compare_check", function(){
          alert("hello");
        });
    });
});
```